# Friendly_id not creating slugs for old records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, slug, friendly-id

I just added the Friendly_id gem to my rails project looking to not use the database id and create a slug, but I can't seem to create slugs for old records. My model looks like this.

```
class Mapping < ActiveRecord::Base

  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :title, use: :slugged

  # Friendly_Id code to only update the url for new records
  def should_generate_new_friendly_id?
    new_record? || slug.blank?
  end

end
```

I then am running `Model.find_each(&:save)` but it keeps spitting out a nil result. I've tried commenting out the `should_generate_new_friendly_id` completely but with no luck. Anyone see what I'm doing wrong here?

**EDIT**
I rolled my database back and rewrote my migratations and that has appeared to have fixed the issue.

Comment: Have you tried to return constant `true` in `should_generate_new_friendly_id?` just for generating slug for the old records?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean here? I'm still pretty new to rails.

Comment: I mean to regenerate nonexisting slugs with this: `def should_generate_new_friendly_id?; true; end` Also, I hope you used `Mapping.find_each(&:save)` and not `Model.find_each(&:save)`.

Comment: From withn rails console or in the model?

Comment: Change the code in the model to the one I wrote, and run the `Mapping.find_each(&:save)` from the console, after you saved the changed model.

Comment: I was using `Mapping.find_each(&:save)`, even with your code I'm the application is still retuning nil

Comment: have you figured this out ? same this is happening with me.

Comment: i have slugs in 2 models, it is working for 1 model but not for 2nd, the function `should_generate_new_friendly_id` not event get called.

Comment: Try:   "new_record? || slug.nil?" in your should_generate_new_friendly_id

Answer (score 2):

If anyone finds this 6 year old question:

Without a "do and end" block:

find_each returns an Enumerable (not an ActiveRecord Class)

Use:

> Model.find_each.select(&:save)

Notice the added "select" method

[Doing stuff with Rails’ find_each](https://medium.com/@jonathanabrams/doing-stuff-with-rails-find-each-3f592ae02136)